# Remove item from list that present in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
inventory = {
        'gold' : [500,50],
        'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], # Assigned a new list to 'pouch' key
        'backpack' : ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf'].sort(),'pocket':      ['seashell','strange berry','lint']
}
```

## for removing 'dagger' in the list stored in the 'backpack' key, i tried:

```
del(inventory['backpack'][1])
```

## and

```
inventory['backpack'].remove(1)
```

## and

```
inventory['backpack'].remove(["backpack"][1])
```

## But stil the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

## What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set `'backpack'` to this:

```
['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf'].sort()
```

`.sort()` sorts a list *in-place* and returns `None`.  So `inventory['backpack']` is `None`.

Either sort the list after you build the inventory:

```
inventory = ...
inventory['backpack'].sort()
```

Or use `sorted`:

```
'backpack': list(sorted(['xylophone', 'dagger', 'bedroll', 'bread loaf'])),
```

Comment: Thank very much :) :), it is done :)
inventory = ...
inventory['backpack'].sort()
inventory['backpack'].remove('dagger') @Eevee

Answer (score 1):

```
['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf'].sort()
```

returns None. Therefore 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'

try

```
sorted(['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf'])
```

instead.

Comment: ... and then `inventory['backpack'].remove('dagger')` to remove the item.

Answer (score 0):

`.sort()` doesn't work this way, it changes the list but returns `None`:

```
x = ['c', 'b', 'a']
x.sort()
print(x)
```

This code will output `['a', 'b', 'c']`, but this code will output `None`:

```
x = ['c', 'b', 'a']
x = x.sort()
print(x)
```

To solve this problem, you have to change your code to:

```
backpack = ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf']
backpack.sort()
inventory = {
        'gold' : [500,50],
        'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], # Assigned a new list to 'pouch' key
        'backpack' : backpack,'pocket':      ['seashell','strange berry','lint']
}
```

Or:

```
inventory = {
        'gold' : [500,50],
        'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], # Assigned a new list to 'pouch' key
        'backpack' : sorted(['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf']),'pocket':      ['seashell','strange berry','lint']
}
```